# How can I commit reversal of last commit?

Tags: git, version-control, undo, revert, git-reset

I've just created a huge commit. Now I want to commit the reversal of these changes.

So basically I want to have the same files in my repo as I'll have after `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, but I'd like to keep the history of my changes, so create a new commit instead of removing the last one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can commit the reversal of one or more commits using [`git-revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert). For instance, to revert the most recent commit:

```
git revert HEAD
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please leave a comment. The answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @AnoE I believe it's because the question is, arguably, a duplicate.

Comment: Yes it's the duplicate, but other question's answer is tl;dr and was hard to find, but this guy solved my issue perfectly in few seconds after posting a question. Thank you! And please don't minus him more :D

Comment: @ferenus Thanks man. :) Also, for the record, although the answer in that other question does answer your question, the title implies a very important difference. Yours is very clear that you're specifically *not* asking for `git-reset` or similar, which is why I'm hesitant to call it a duplicate myself.

Comment: Alright, the wonders of intermingling realtime answers/comments. :)